# Consulta no MySQL com itens indesejáveis - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array

Preciso comparar dois arrays que voltam do MySQL, porém um deles está voltando com vários itens estranhos, impossibilitando minha comparação. Já filtrei na busca para voltar apenas o campo que eu quero, mas não tem jeito...

Deem uma olhada no código pra entenderem melhor:

```
public function listarNomes(){
$oConexao = new conexaoclass();
$oConexao -> abrirConexao();
$this -> sql = "SELECT Nome FROM Professores 
                ORDER BY Nome;";

$this -> resultado = mysql_query($this -> sql, $oConexao -> getConn());
}
```

Aqui vai a chamada:

```
include_once 'classes/professoresclass.php';

$oProfessor = new professoresclass();
$oProfessor ->listarNomes();          

while ($arrayProfessores = mysql_fetch_array($oProfessor->retorno())){
    $array2[] = $arrayProfessores['Nome'];
}

foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
    echo 'teste<br>';
}
```

Tenho apenas 3 nomes cadastrados no banco mas esse 'teste' aparece varias vezes... Fiz um var_dump() no array2 e aparece o seguinte:

```
array (size=11)

0 => string '1' (length=1)
'idSemestre' => string '1' (length=1)

1 => string '2014/2' (length=6)
'Nome' => string '2014/2' (length=6)

2 => string '2014-11-28' (length=10)
'DataDeInicio' => string '2014-11-28' (length=10)

3 => string '2014-12-05' (length=10)
'DataDeTermino' => string '2014-12-05' (length=10)

4 => string 'Administrador Máximo' (length=21)

5 => string 'Carlos Maltz' (length=12)

6 => string 'João Sem Braço' (length=16)
```

Eu realmente tenho esses dados que estão vindo a mais cadastrados em outros setores do sistema, porém só preciso dos três últimos nesse array... Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por padrão, o resultado do `mysql-fetch-array` vem com índices numéricos e também com índices correspondentes ao nome do banco. Se quer só uma das duas coisas, precisa utilizar o segundo parâmetro:

```
$arrayProfessores = mysql_fetch_array( $oProfessor->retorno(), MYSQL_ASSOC )
```

Vai retornar

```
'idSemestre' => '1'
```

Por outro lado, se quiser só índices numéricos:

```
$arrayProfessores = mysql_fetch_array( $oProfessor->retorno(), MYSQL_NUM )
```

E o resultado vai ser:

```
0 => '1'
```

Deixar de especificar o segundo parâmetro, como você está fazendo, é o mesmo que definir como `MYSQL_BOTH`: cada resultado retornará duas vezes, uma vez com índice numérico, outra com o nome/*alias* da coluna como índice.

Mais detalhes no [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) sobre o `mysql_fetch_array`.

Comment: Pois é, mas tem algo estranho aí... Pq eu faço a mesma coisa em outro array, no array1 ali naquele código e funciona, vem apenas o campo que eu quero... Vou editar a pergunta e botar esse array1 pra vc dar uma olhada